# Insert more than one item from a belongs_to association using nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my Rails way, I have just found another question to the commmunity.

I have the following project: I have a calendar which render me the events that any client have dealed with my company. If I want to insert a new event with only one client, I have no problem, but if I want to insert a new event with more than one client, I have a problem.

But it's been impossible to insert more than one client at the same time. I know that with this configuration, Rails only accepts one client for every instance of event, and one solution could be change the association model between Event and Client, but it makes no sense for me (event has_many clients and client belongs_to events... sounds weird). So, this post it's related to compile options from the community.

This is my code (I'm using the nested_form gem by Ryan Bates [github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git]):

UPDATE: By the moment, I introduce a new model Group, in this way:

models/group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
  has_many :events

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events

  attr_accessible :events_attributes, :clients_attributes
end
```

models/client.rb

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  belongs_to :group

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group, :update_only => true

  attr_accessible :name, :surname, :email, :group_attributes, :events_attributes
end
```

models/event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group, :update_only => true

  attr_accessible :title, :group_id, :starts_at, :ends_at, :group_attributes
end
```

views/events/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.fields_for :group do |group_form| %>
    <%= group_form.fields_for :clients do |client_form| %>
      <%= client_form.input :name %>
      <%= client_form.input :surname %>
      <%= client_form.input :email, :as => :email %>
      <%= client_form.link_to_remove "Remove this client" %>
    <% end %>
<%= group_form.link_to_add "Add another client", :clients %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :starts_at, :as => :datetime %>
  <%= f.input :ends_at, :as => :datetime %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

But know, my problem is that, when I create an event for one group, this group is successfully create when I insert ONLY ONE client. When I try to insert two or more clients I get the next:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: new_1332430522879):
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:44:in `new'
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:44:in `create'
```

Ah! And I forget to comment before (but I think that is not relevant for that), that I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p125 and Rails 3.2.2

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance...

Foncho

Comment: This sounds backwards: if a Client has_many Events, shouldn't the nested_form_for be for @client rather than @event?  In your models, Client is the parent, and Event is the child.

Comment: Yes @Eric, but I need to create an Event and indicated what clients are involved... Do you know what I mean? I think if I create an intermediate model (such as Group) should be work, but I want to know more options...

Comment: If a Client has many Events, and Event has many Clients, then it sounds like a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.  See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association).

Comment: Thanks @EricK, maybe you're right, but I would prefer not to use the Joins table solution... I will try, afterwards...

Comment: @EricK if I use your solutions, creating a clients_events_join_table I get the next message:

    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "clients_events" ("event_id", "client_id") VALUES (1, 1)):

Comment: problem solved deleting the line _t.timestamps_ from join migration